# Display a specific array on the template

Tags: angular

I have a `sender` and a `receiver` component that are connected via `data` service. In template for `sender`, there is an input field that I can type a number and by clicking on a button, the number is sent to the `receiver` and stored in variable `arr`. In `receiver` I have a number of object arrays. What I need is based on what number is entered by the user, information from the relevant list being displayed (0: Colleagues, 1: Customers, 2: Friends, etc).
 I don't want to have several `div`s on the template, each being rendered depending on what `arr` is. I rather want to have only one div that does this for me.

**Code for service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {

  private defaultArray = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  currentArray = this.defaultArray.asObservable();

  changeArray (arr: number) {
    this.defaultArray.next (arr);
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

**Code for sender:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sender',
  template: `<button (click)="changeArray(inp.value)">Change Array</button>
              <input type='number' #inp>
              `,
  styleUrls: ['./sender.component.css']
})
export class SenderComponent implements OnInit {
  arr: number;

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  changeArray (inp){
    this.data.changeArray (inp);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentArray.subscribe(arr => this.arr= arr);
  }

}
```

**Code for receiver:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-receiver',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let list of listofList[arr]">
           {{list.Name}}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  `,
  styleUrls: ['./receiver.component.css']
})
export class ReceiverComponent implements OnInit {
  arr: number;    

  Colleagues = [
    {
      Name:'Jack N',
      Age:25,
      Title: 'Intern'
    },
    {
      Name:'Susan A',
      Age:22,
      Title: 'Developer'
    },
    {
      Name: 'Pete Z',
      Age:30,
      colleagueTitle: 'Bookkeeper'
    }
  ];


Customers = [
  {
    Name:'Sara B',
    State:'CA',
    badCredit: false
  },
  {
    Name: 'Donald F',
    State: 'WA',
    badCredit: false
  }
];

Friends = [
  {
    Name: 'Carl G',
    foodRequirement: 'Gluten-free Bread'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Filipa O',
    foodRequirement: 'Low-lactose milk'
  },
  {
    productCode: 'DER5509',
    productName: 'Dark Chocolate'
  }
]


listofList =[this.Colleagues, this.Customers, this.Products];

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentArray.subscribe()
  }

}
```

I have tested and I can see that the communication between the components is working fine. However, By sending and receiving a new array number (`arr`), still the default list is displayed. While I want a new list displayed after the value of `arr`.

Could you please review my code and help me find out the problem?

Comment: What exactly doesn't work of the code you posted?

Comment: By sending and receiving a new array number (arr), still the default list is displayed. I want a new list displayed after the value of arr.

Comment: Why do you use an `*ngFor` in your receiver component if your goal is to show only one array?

Comment: What do you mean?
I have used `*ngFor ` to go through the whole array and display data.

Comment: OK I see what you are trying to do here, I've posted an asnwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you simply needed to update the relevant variable in the receiver component after the input.

This is a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atoilt) that shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `arr` from `ReceiverComponent` is never updated by your service.

This should do the job:

```
this.data.currentArray.subscribe(arr => this.arr = arr)
```

Comment: I just tried this, but it did not help:
 `ngOnInit() {
    this.data.currentArray.subscribe(arr => this.arr = arr)
  }`

Comment: if you add a `console.log(arr)` inside the `subscribe` do you see your number ?